# Type for keys in object, where value of that key satisfies constraint

Tags: typescript, type-constraints

I have something like this:

Obviously this is an overly minimal example so the question of why I would want to do these types specifically is irrelevant.

```js
type Bird = { kind: "bird" }
type Fish = { kind: "fish" }

const zoo = {
  flamingo: { kind: "bird" },
  hawk: { kind: "bird" },
  chicken: { kind: "bird" },
  guppy: { kind: "fish" },
  blowfish: { kind: "fish" }
}
```

I want to get string array types that might be this:

```js
type FishInZoo = "guppy" | "blowfish"
type BirdInZoo = "flamingo" | "hawk" | "chicken"
```

So I'm thinking something like the following, but I don't know what the syntax would be:

```js
type FishInZoo = keyof typeof zoo where { kind: "fish" }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like:

```js
type GetKeysOfType<
  Type extends Record<string, any>,
  Obj extends Record<string, any>
> = keyof {
    [Key in keyof Obj as Obj[Key] extends Type ? Key : never]: Obj[Key];
}
```

Do note this will require `as const` assertion on the object [see docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). This allows you to use the string literal in the object and type i.e.

```js
type Bird = { kind: "bird" }
type Fish = { kind: "fish" }

// as opposed to
type Kind = { kind: string };
```

Using this will require you to specify:

```js
const zoo = {
  flamingo: { kind: "bird" },
  hawk: { kind: "bird" },
  chicken: { kind: "bird" },
  guppy: { kind: "fish" },
  blowfish: { kind: "fish" }
} as const // this as const.
```

Then you use the type like this:

```js
type BirdsInZoo = GetKeysOfType<Bird, typeof zoo>
type FishesInZoo = GetKeysOfType<Fish, typeof zoo>
```

You can also enforce that all objects that use `GetKeysOfType` have to be `Readonly` i.e. have to use `as const` to prevent people from forgetting and receiving incorrect values. but that would depend on your use case.

It uses the relatively new [key remapping feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) released in 4.1.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQglgJwCZQLxQN5QNZwHZIBcUARAEaJIlQC+AUKJFAGJwDOAFmpjvkaQDN2HavToBjAPZ42wKAC9Jk7hjpQoAgDYBDALb4A5pOJZcBYuUqiANGqgdtAd2wne50hWQ274jnHHYEHiuZvyWXrS26gYArmBgICF8FkKc3upkmpKOqRxJ7iS5onQ0UNpsUFIywADcdAzg0ABaSgAqjdyMEJICCkp1DUwA4hDAANIQIGwA8gLtkAA8dvPQEAAewEFIFQBKEFLIC7IIhtZleCAAfFFQ02QAVlDrmwS7+5KHx6fnV3SX3IEQD1MHZ1ABtCYgKD4HCTYF3R7lW4PCGTAC6Tw2WwqKygAH4oJCoMQ8BAAG4QBBo4gI1EgNF1MRdKAAQW4I3Gkxmc0aC3gyDOLUkK0uNSAA)

Comment: Wow thank you! That first code fragment is a little hard to follow (not your fault!) but once I realized that you then *use* that type like `type Birds = GetKeysOfType<Bird, typeof zoo>` I see that it's the perfect solution! I'm going to edit your answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @zecuria's great answer above, there are a few additional caveats, related to my actual usage of this type.

```
type GetKeysOfType<
  Type extends Record<string, any>,
  Obj extends Record<string, any>
> = keyof {
  [Key in keyof Obj as Obj[Key] extends Type ? Key : never]: Obj[Key];
};

const initialFilters = {
  sportId: { key: "sportId", kind: "type", types: [] as String[] },
  gameType: { key: "gameType", kind: "type", types: [] as String[] },
  contestTypeId: { key: "contestTypeId", kind: "type", types: [] as String[] },
  entryFees: {
    kind: "range",
    key: "entryFees",
    max: 10000,
    min: 0,
  },
} as const;

type TypeFilterKey = GetKeysOfType<TypeFilter, typeof initialFilters>;
```

Of importance is the `as String[]` on the object values in `initialFilters`.

Without it, `types` will be of type `readonly []`, instead of the mutable `String[]`, and something like

```js
filter.types.includes(type)
```

will fail with

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.